# Allow anonymous comments just in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

Is it possible to allow anonymous comments in a CPT? I mean, this config:

- Allow registered users to comment globally.
- Allow anonymous users to comment in a CPT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way around this but I would allow comments on the entire site and make sure that your custom post type supports comments:

```
<?php 
register_post_type( 'custom', array(
    // ..
    supports => array(
        'comments',
    ),
) );
?>
```

Then add the following function to your `functions.php` file:

```
function hide_comment_form( $post_type = 'custom' )
{
    // If user is logged in return false
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return false;
    } else {

        // Else check for special post type
        // If on custom post type single return false           
        if ( is_singular( $post_type ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        // Else return true (hide the form)
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can then wrap your `comment_form()` code within the template in the following:

```
if ( ! hide_comment_form() ) {
    comment_form();
}
```

The function will always hide the comment form when a user isn't logged in, except when the comment form appears on a custom post type page.

If you didn't want to edit your template file you could also add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
function comment_form_before_function()
{
    if ( hide_comment_form() ) {
        echo '<div style="display: none;">';
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'comment_form_before_function', 1 );

function comment_form_after_function()
{
    if ( hide_comment_form() ) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'comment_form_after_function', 99 );
```